# Chef client run root.sh for NMO setuid status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, chef-infra, setuid, chef-client

I need to run `root.sh` as root user and then restart the OEM agent as user "xxxxx". Which involves changing permissions of some folders and files and setting the SETUID bit along with permission changes.

And this will resolve an error called "NMO error".

Now Chef runs the `root.sh` as root and also restarts OEM agent as "xxxxxx".
Each step returns correct output, without any error. But the issue doesn't get resolved.

And if we run the same steps manually, the issue will get resolve immediately.

```rb
execute 'rootSH' do
  user 'root'
  command "root.sh"
  action :nothing
end
```

```
resources(execute: 'rootSH').run_action(:run)
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any logs or anything to look at!!! Will try to answer though..

Make a small change as below :

```
execute 'rootSH' do
  user 'root'
  command "sh root.sh"
  cwd "/path/to/root.sh" # ENTER THE PATH TO ROOT.SH HERE
  live_stream true  
end.run_action(:run)
```

Let me know if it works. Else, post the logs.

Comment: The command executes successfully. However the issue doesnt get resolved.

[2020-09-16T12:17:21+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[rootSH] action run (XXXx::XXXX line 76)

    [execute]
              Finished product-specific root actions.
              /etc exist
[2020-09-16T12:17:21+00:00] INFO: execute[rootSH] ran successfully
[2020-09-16T12:17:21+00:00] INFO: execute[rootSH] ran successfully
    - execute sh root.sh

Comment: I need more information to go on. Like : What are you trying to achieve ?, The contents of the root.sh script , Logs from the chef-client run.